# Problems with DNSMasq (Port 53 error, Ubuntu 18)

Tags: ubuntu, dns, port, dnsmasq

I'm creating an **apache web server** in **Ubuntu Desktop 18** (via **VirtualBox**).
I just installed **DNSmasq**, but the application is not working properly.

These are the errors:

[image: Errors]

I also checked the ports, but I dont even know which process is using my port 53:

[image: Netstat]

I would really appreciate if you help me out.

**EDIT**

[image: lsof]

***P.D.:*** In the network section, in VirtualBox, i'm using Bridged Adapter, maybe it's relevant...

Comment: Although I inlined the images, this is text from your terminal window.  So why the screen prints?  Text can be cut-paste in here, so do not put screen images of text please.  Please edit.  Why?  I cannot cut-paste text in the image into a translator to know what "La directon ..." actually means in English :-)

Comment: Your port 53 is already used (If my translation is good).  So you have something else already using the port, or you are trying to start a second instance.  Turn it off and see if port 53 is used.  If it is, run `sudo lsof` to see which process uses it.

Comment: @Nic3500 https://gyazo.com/30d6eca4ebdfc61259436b1a978ec8bc that's the supposed process which is using port 53

Comment: Hi, post here, I will not click this link (I am at work, and I do not know what this link is).  As text, remember no images of text :-)

Comment: @Nic3500 Sorry man, post edited. There's the result. I pasted the image since I just cannot copy-paste the test. It would be a mess

Comment: Paste your text, and format it as code (the '{}` icon on top of the editor).  You will see, it keeps formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`systemd-resolver` is already binding to port 53 hence `dnsmasq` can not use it.

If you are sure you want `dnsmasq` you will first need to disable this systemd service like that:

```
 systemctl stop systemd-resolver
 systemctl disable systemd-resolver
```

Then starting `dnsmasq` should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stop systemd-resolver,
you can change the port that dnsmasq uses

- add/edit `port=<port>` in /etc/dnsmasq.conf
- then `systemctl restart dnsmasq`